# Too many users?

Tags: audit

I am a novice college student taking an entry-level Linux Red Hat. I ran `cat /etc/passwd` and got all the accounts.

Is this right or do I have visitors?

```
[jlj0325@poseidon ~]$ awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd
root
bin
daemon
adm
lp
sync
shutdown
halt
mail
operator
games
ftp
nobody
dbus
polkitd
avahi
avahi-autoipd
postfix
sshd
instructor
jlj0325
systemd-network
geoclue
chrony
usbmuxd
rtkit
tss
openvpn
abrt
pulse
lightdm
setroubleshoot
nm-openconnect
nm-openvpn
nx
```

Comment: really easy to figure this out: compare your list with a list from a fresh install with the same configuration

Answer (score 4):

No, this is by design. Many of these are daemon accounts which have no privileges except what are necessary. This means that if say OpenVPN has a remote code execution vulnerability they can’t immediately own your computer. This is the general idea of “least privilege” but applied to computer permissions for applications.